# Branch banking in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, banking

It has been many decades but is it still true that in the UK you can do your banking only at the branch where you open your current account and not any other branch of the same bank like in the US?

Comment: Technically, there are sill some companies that might ask or require your original branch, but I haven't stepped inside my original branch in almost a decade. Everything is online now. The concept is kind of obsolete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this topic applies to anyone, expats and native citizens alike.

Comment: @ouflak I agree, but I can't think of anywhere else that Gary could have posted the question instead.

Comment: @user1068122 on-topic on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

No longer true. In fact you are just as likely to be offered a chair and telephone and have to talk to their call centre from within the branch.